# Twilio Runtime <Say> and <Play> Verbs Ending Call

Tags: twilio

I am trying to write a simple function to play a recorded message and then say a dynamic message, but I'm running into some trouble... the function will play and say what I want it to, but then the call abruptly ends. Oddly, though, the flow log says that the call is still engaged... and when I go into the flow Steps, it tells me that the function event was a success and it transitioned to the next widget. 
I tried testing the HelloVoice template function to see what would happen, and the same thing occurs. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make the call continue? Thanks!

My code:

```
    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    var play1 = event.play1; //recorded msg URL
    var say1 = event.say1; //person-specific message

    twiml.play(play1);
    twiml.say(
            {
                voice: 'woman',
                language: 'es',
            },
            say1);

    callback(null, twiml);
```

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, there is this statement at the end in the troubleshooting section.

Studio User Guide
https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide

Returning custom TwiML from an HTTP Request or Function widget isn't yet supported. It will be soon.

The reason your call ends is your TwiML ends